# Getting an error on my (first ever) CardGameViewController

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting the error `incompatible pointer types assigning to Deck *__strong from PlayCards *`

And i'm not sure why is that. Its in the first method implemented (deck):

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCards.h"


@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cardLabel;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger flipsCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Deck *deck;
@end


@implementation CardGameViewController




-(Deck *) deck {

    if (!_deck) _deck = [[PlayingCards alloc] init];
    return _deck;
}


-(void) setFlipsCount:(NSUInteger)flipsCount {

    _flipsCount = flipsCount;
    self.cardLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips:%d", self.flipsCount];

}


- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {

    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;

    self.flipsCount++;

}


@end
```

This is the header file(nothing going on here):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import "Card.h"
//#import "Deck.h"
//#import "PlayingCards.h"

@interface CardGameViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

And the PlayingCard class inheriting from Deck class..

this is the PlayingCards.m

```
#import "PlayingCards.h"


@implementation PlayingCards

@synthesize suit = _suit;

//modifying the contents getter so it will return array with the ranks and rank+suit 
-(NSString *) contents {

    NSArray *cardsRank = [PlayingCards rankStrings];

    return [cardsRank[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
}

//creating a method to make sure we get validated suits
+(NSArray *) validSuit {

    return @[@"♠",@"♣",@"♥",@"♦"];
}

//creating calss method to validate the rank
+(NSArray *) rankStrings {

    return @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
}

//creating a new setter for suit to make sure we get the valitated suits, uding the validateSuit method
-(void) setSuit:(NSString *)suit {

    if ([[PlayingCards validSuit] containsObject:suit]) {
        _suit = suit;
    }
}

//creating new getter for suit to make sure its not empty
-(NSString *) suit {

    return _suit? _suit: @"?";
}

//creating a class method to make sure when user set the rank he will will
+(NSUInteger) maxRank {

    return [self rankStrings].count - 1;

}

//creating a new setter to the renk to make sure the rank is validates 
-(void) setRank:(NSUInteger)rank {

    if (rank <= [PlayingCards maxRank]) {

        _rank = rank;
    }
}

@end
```

PlayingCards.h

```
#import "Card.h"
#import "Deck.h"

@interface PlayingCards : Card

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;

+(NSArray *) validSuit;

+(NSUInteger) maxRank;


@end
```

Comment: Is the synthesize missing or did you just leave it out?

Comment: What does the initializer for PlayingCards look like?

Comment: I left it out..@cardmagik

Comment: I added the PlayingCards.m @CodaFi

Comment: Could you add PlayingCards.h as well ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's `PlayingCards : Deck`, not `Deck : PlayingCards`?

Comment: @JohnBigs You are trying to assign an instance of type PlayingCards, which inherits from `Card` to a variable of type `Deck`. What are the parent class for `Card`? is `Deck` among them?

Comment: the parent class for Card is NSObject @Jean

Comment: @JohnBigs Then it cannot work. See my answer. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: There are too many comments flying around. John, please update your question with just the relevant parts. Show just the .h files for `Deck`, `PlayingCards`, and `Cards` (and any other class you created in the hierarchy). Then show just the line giving an error. There is no need for the view controller .h files.

Comment: you right, i need to fix couple of things in the code and i will update it asap, thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
if (!_deck) _deck = [[PlayingCards alloc] init];
```

Should be:

```
if (!_deck) _deck = [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
```

Comment: Or the `deck` property should be `PlayingCards` instead of `Deck`.

Comment: but PlayingCards inherits from Deck, so why cant this work? I need the PlayingCards (its a playing cards deck) allocated and initialized @rmaddy

Comment: No, `PlayingCards` inherits from `Card`.

Comment: I meant Daeck inherits from PlayingCards @rmaddy

Comment: `PlayingCards : Card` this reads as: "Class PlayingCards is a subclass of class Card".  I'm not sure how you got the idea that it's a deck subclass

Comment: @JohnBigs You can't assign a more general class to a more specific class. You can assign a `Deck` object to a `PlayingCards` variable but not the other way around (like you are trying).

Comment: @rmaddy, actually it should be PlayingCardDeck, assuming he's following the Stanford course example.

Comment: @CodaFi He got the idea from the question: `And the PlayingCard class inheriting from Deck class..`

Comment: PlayingCardDeck inherits fromDeck which inherits from NSObject.

Comment: what is PlayingCardsDeck? you meant PlayingCards? @rdelmar

Comment: No. Are you following the Stanford course? PlayingCardDeck is a subclass of Deck. PlayingCards inherits from Card.

Comment: Yes im following the course, so I might missed something there damn..sorry@rdelmar

Comment: Now i got your answer @rdelmar

Answer (score 0):

If the parent for Card is of class `NSObject` as you say, and given that `PlayingCards` inherits from Card, then you can't assign an instance of `PlayingCards` to a variable of type `Deck*`. That's what the compiler is telling you.

If you really need to do it, you have to write:

```
 if (!_deck) _deck = (Deck*)[[PlayingCards alloc] init];
```

It would only be valid because in Objective-C the implementation is given at runtime and which method of which class is called is only decided at runtime when the message is dispatched. However, this pattern is very unusual and you better be certain that PlayingCards is implementing all the selectors that might be called on a `Deck` instance. A better way would be to use protocols.

You can define a protocol and then use:

```
id <myProtocol> deck = [[PlayingCards alloc] init];
```

Put in the protocol all the selectors you need.

Why can't you use this ?

```
PlayingCards* deck = [[PlayingCards alloc] init];
```

Comment: this is the instructor line http://d.pr/i/IcFp see if you be able to see this @jean

Comment: @Jean Using a cast like you did just to get rid of a compiler warning is BAD. It will just crash eventually at runtime.

Comment: Then using `(Deck*)` will do that. But you **may** get a crash (exception) later-on at runtime.

Comment: @maddy Yes. That's what I said. A better way would be to use protocols. Which brings us back to :`What are you trying to achieve ?`